# 'settingsForTypes(_:categories:)' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:categories:)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate

I tried to translate this objective-c code to swift:

objective-c:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
            UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                          categories:nil]];
  }

...
```

swift:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            if UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings.settingsForTypes([UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound], categories: nil))
            }

...
```

API signature:

```
// categories may be nil or an empty set if custom user notification actions will not be used
+ (instancetype)settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationType)types
                      categories:(nullable NSSet<UIUserNotificationCategory *> *)categories; // instances of UIUserNotificationCategory
```

but I get an error which I dont understand. After all I pass 2 params to `otificationSettings.settingsForTypes`  and not just one as the compiler complains.

How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it’s telling you is that you don’t need to call the class method `+settingsForTypes:categories:` to construct the UIUserNotificationSettings object—you just use its [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) instead.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [ .Alert, .Badge, .Sound ], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 and 4:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

iOS 10+:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
    print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
}
```